# Homotopy intuition about why two disjoint disks in $D^2$ are homotopic to a point in $D^2$

Tags: intuition, homotopy-theory

If $Y$ is contractible and $X$ is any space, then any $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ are homotopic.

Let $Y=D^2$ the unit disk in $\Bbb R^2$ and let $X$ be two smaller disjoint disks lying within $D^2$.

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ by the inclusion map of the two disks into $D^2$ and let $g : X \rightarrow Y$ be the map sending all points to the $0$ point.

Since the two maps are homotopic, the two disks in $D^2$ are homotpic to a point.

My questions are:

**(1) What exactly is a homotopy that continuously deforms two disks into a single point?**

**(2) Is there a better "intuitive" understanding of homotopy besides: shrinking and expanding objects by compressing and identifying "touching" points together or vice versa**?

Because the fact that two disks are homotopic to a point in $D^2$ defies the visual analogy I created when thinking about homotopy.

Comment: "...defies the visual analogy I created when thinking about homotopy" Do you mean homotopy equivalence? If so, begin homotopic to inclusion does not mean  homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y = D^2$ is not just contractible, but in fact a convex subset of $\Bbb R^2$, a straight-line homotopy works:
$$
H : X \times I \to Y, \qquad (x, t) \mapsto (1 - t)x.
$$
This homotopy shrinks the two circles down to points while simultaneously moving them along a straight line to the origin.

Comment: Is there a better intuitive understanding of homotopy that you can think of?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; I visualize it as the two circles shrinking to points while moving to the origin. (In general, a homotopy might involve continuous "reshaping" rather than just resizing and sliding). Is there something in particular about this visualization that you find unconvincing or unsatisfying?